# Facebook app - Silent "Protocols must match" error

Tags: facebook, http, iframe, https, facebook-login

Here is my current login flow for my Facebook app (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17539470/1397061) for an explanation).  `logout()` and `login()` are dummy functions that render the page when the user is logged out or logged in.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
    FB.init({
        appId: '...',
        channelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/channel.html',
        status: false,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: false,
        oauth: true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            login(response);
        } else {
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                login(response);
            });
            logout();
        }
    });
};
```

With this login flow, I don't have to reload the page when the user logs in, but I get the silent error:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.facebook.com" from accessing a
>   frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com".  The frame
>   requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed
>   has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

I assume that reloading the page transfers the iframe holding the app to the `https://` protocol, but I don't really understand why or what that means.  Why is this error occurring, and is it something to be concerned about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a security issue in most browsers. You cant ajax an https link from a http page

possible duplicate of [Facebook gives "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL" error in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577947/facebook-gives-unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url-error-in-chr)