# How to login to Facebook with a login button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

My app has a Facebook login button (`<fb:login-button>`) which logs the user into Facebook and authenticates their use of my app.  Here is my code (`login()` and `logout()` prepare the page layout for being logged in and logged out, respectively).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17539470/1397061) for the reasoning behind this code.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
        appId: myAppID,
        channelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//' 
            + window.location.host + '/channel.html',
        status: false,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: false,
        oauth: true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            login(response);
        } else {
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                login(response);
            });
            logout();
        }
    });
}

(function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

The problem: new users get the Oauth dialog and can log into Facebook, but `auth.login` doesn't fire for them.  Neither do `auth.authResponseChange` and `auth.statusChange` (all described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)).  The next time the user presses the button, or if they were already logged into Facebook, **the dialog pops up and immediately disappears**.  (Strangely, the callbacks do occur as expected with my own Facebook account, perhaps because I've authenticated the app previously.)

As a work-around, I've tried triggering `FB.login()` as a manual onclick event for the login-button (pardon the use of inline Javascript):

```
<fb:login-button onclick="FB.login(function(r){if(r.authResponse)login(r)})">
```

but this doesn't trigger the login callback either (though it does log the user in).

**What is the correct way to login to Facebook with a login button?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out any of these ways to login are fine, I just forgot to disable "Sandbox mode" in my app's settings on developers.facebook.com:

> "If enabled, only app developers will be able to use app."

Whoops.